# How can I see what datasets belong to which data flows?

Tags: einstein-analytics, data-set

I have inherited a messy Wave setup.
The data set view shows data set by app.
I would like to know what data flow it is a part of.
Where can I learn this basic info about my own data?
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvmWs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Source for the dataset and any flow it's a part of by going to the Data Manager (in Analytics Studio, click on the gear icon, and then click 'Data Manager').

In the Data Manager, click on the 'Data' tab and then find the dataset you want to examine. Click on the menu arrow in the rightmost column and click 'Edit Dataset'.

You'll see the source under 'Source' and anywhere else it's used under 'Usage'

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of hoping for a way to see them in the list. This is a tedious process to investigate.